# Multiple conditions with OR || in 'if' statement JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators, or-operator

I am trying to write multiple conditions in the one 'if' statement with OR.

sudo code I am trying to write:

if the status is empty navigate, if the status is 'completed' navigate, if the status is 'failed' navigate.

This is my code so far:

```
   if ((_.isEmpty($scope.status)) || ($scope.status != ('completed' || 'failed'))) {
        return frameworkService.navigateTo('giftcardWelcome');
    }
```

The _.isEmpty check works, the checking if status is 'completed' works, but when checking the || for 'failed' it is not executing this.

Can someone explain to me why and how to write it correctly please? I know I could write a widened out if statement but wanted a clean refactored way.

Comment: `('completed' || 'failed')` === `'completed'` - because that's how javascript works - you need to check equality individually ... `($scope.status != 'completed' &&  $scope.status != 'failed')` - note `&&` not `||` ... because `$scope.status != 'completed' || $scope.status != 'failed'` will ALWAYS be true - because of logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `$scope.status != ('completed' || 'failed')` really works as it looks, it does a logical OR between `'completed'` and `'failed'`, and then compares the result of that expression against `$scope.status`.

The result of `'completed' || 'failed'` will be `'completed'`, so that means your condition is really equivalent to `$scope.status != 'completed'`.

If you want to make sure that `$scope.status` is not equal to either string, you need to compare against each string explicitly: `($scope.status != 'completed' && $scope.status != 'failed')`.

Comment: Yes, I see it now after you explained it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

`('completed' || 'failed')` === `'completed'` - because that's how javascript works - you need to check equality individually ...

You'll need

```
|| ($scope.status != 'completed' &&  $scope.status != 'failed')
```

note `&&` not `||` ... because `$scope.status != 'completed' || $scope.status != 'failed'` will ALWAYS be true - because of logic

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.status != ('completed' || 'failed')
```

This does not do what you think it does. In JavaScript `A || B` returns `A` if it is truthy, otherwise `B`; since `'completed'` is truthy, this is equivalent to

```
$scope.status != 'completed'
```

In order to check whether `$scope.status` is one of the two values, you need to either check both are different explicitly (note `&&`, not `||`):

```
$scope.status != 'completed' && $scope.status != 'failed')
```

or test that it is not in a set (or another container):

```
let endSet = new Set(['completed', 'failed']);
// ...

endSet.has($scope.status)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation :)